# How To Reinstall Sudo, if it is not in the sources.list?

Tags: software-installation, sudo, kali-linux

I accidentally (yea, go on, laugh) removed sudo from my linux..
Googling, I found the "apt-get install sudo" command.
The problem with that is, that i get the message:

```
Package 'sudo' has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone know which repository i need to add to my sources.list in order for it to download sudo?

Comment: Can you try running `apt-get update` (as root) first? There appears to be some [tracking information](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/sudo) for Kali's `sudo` package... You might also want to have a look [here](http://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq) and [here](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories).

Comment: Got this reply 
"# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done".
Also, when i do "whereis sudo" i get this: "sudo:     "

So, still no luck..

Comment: OK, now you have run `apt-get update`, what's the output of `apt-get install sudo` now (run as root)?

Answer (score -1):

```
pkexec apt-get install sudo
pkexec apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Can you add some more details. So that the OP can have better understanding.